# Small gap around tikz node

Tags: circuitikz

There is a small gap in a named node of mine. It seems to propagate through to the first connected component who gets shifted slightly off.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {};
    \draw (opamp.-) to[short, -*] ++(-1,0) node[] (minus) {};
    
    \draw (minus) to ++(-1,0)
    to[R] ++(-1,0)
    to[short, -o] ++(-1,0);
    
    \draw (minus) to ++(0,1)
    to ++(-1, 0)
    to[R] ++(-1,0)
    to[short, -o] ++(-1,0);
    
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
```

This is what I get when i render it.

[image: Slight gap around the filled circle.]

There's a very slight gap around the filled circle. Also, the connected resistances are slightly shifted. Any idea why this is, and how it can be fixed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.) the minus-coordinate: This is due to the inner/outer sep of tikznodes.
Use one of the following solutions:

- (prefered) use `coordinate(minus)`, if you only want to save a coordinate
- use `(minus.center)` each time you want to address your coordinate
- use `node[inner sep=0](minus)` to set the inner sep to 0
- use `node[coordinate](minus)` to set the inner sep to 0

2.) The resistor: Just use a longer connection, because the resistorshape has a fixed length and your path is too short to draw it correctly.

Best regards,
Stefan

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you kindly.